# How can I reset newtxtext superiors to "normal"/unscaled size?

Tags: chemistry, times

When using `newtxtext`, superiors (used for, say, footnotes) are scaled a bit (per the documentation). However, the `mhchem` package produces subscripts/superscripts in chemical formulae that match the math-mode style, which causes an inconsistent look in-text that I would like to avoid. Is there a way to "reset" the `newtxtext` superiors to match the others? Thanks for any help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

Footnote.\footnote{hi} Another one.\footnote{hello} \ce{Br2} and \ce{CO3^{2-}}

\begin{equation}
F = k_{\textnormal{e}}\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, try `\usepackage[defaultsups=true]{newtxtext}`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Thank you! That is exactly what I needed. I completely overlooked that in the documentation.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your comment, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defaultsups=true]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

Footnote.\footnote{hi} Another one.\footnote{hello} \ce{Br2} and \ce{CO3^{2-}}

\begin{equation}
F = k_{\textnormal{e}}\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

See page 3 of the documentation